Append new lines to string in yaml with yq
I am trying to append a following Variable to my yaml
GROUPS="\ng, ZI-LNX_1, role:metadata-viewer \ng, ZI-LNX_2, role:metadata-viewer \n"

Yaml looks like this
...
             rbac:
                policy.csv: |-
                  p, role:metadata-viewer, repositories, get, */*, allow
                  p, role:metadata-viewer, logs, get, */*, allow
                  g, ZI-LNX__O_EA_0, role:metadata-viewer

I want that new lines come like this:
...
             rbac:
                policy.csv: |-
                  p, role:metadata-viewer, repositories, get, */*, allow
                  p, role:metadata-viewer, logs, get, */*, allow
                  g, ZI-LNX__O_EA_0, role:metadata-viewer
                  g, ZI-LNX_1, role:metadata-viewer
                  g, ZI-LNX_2, role:metadata-viewer

But all I try totally ruins the whole string or inserts the variable as one line with \n
I tried both env() and strenv(), also different styles
yq -i 'rbac."policy.csv" += strenv(GROUPS)  | ... style=""' file.yaml

Edit: with the help of the comment from below, I do now that:
groups="\ng, ZI-LNX_1, role:metadata-viewer \ng, ZI-LNX_2, role:metadata-viewer \n"
export groups=$(cat <<EOF
$(echo -e "$groups")
EOF
)
yq -i 'rbac."policy.csv" += (env(groups)  | . style="literal")' file.yaml

But somehow the first \n disappears:
...
             rbac:
                policy.csv: |-
                  p, role:metadata-viewer, repositories, get, */*, allow
                  p, role:metadata-viewer, logs, get, */*, allow
                  g, ZI-LNX__O_EA_0, role:metadata-viewerg, ZI-LNX_1, role:metadata-viewer
                  g, ZI-LNX_2, role:metadata-viewer


Several issues: First, don't overwrite the system vaiable GROUPS. Use lowercase varnames instead. Then, you don't want to remove the style but retain the "literal" style (|-). Also, if you set it, you want to do it for that item, not the entire document, so I'd use parens and/or restrict the traversal this value, e.g. … += (env(groups) | . style="literal"). But the major issue is that the YAML value is a multiline string while the imported variable just contains literal sequences of the characters \ and n. Can you change that? Otherwise you'd need to make yq replace them with newlines

Hi thank you! your advice about (env(groups) | . style="literal") works almost, but I am missing the first linebreak. I will edit my question. How can you convert \n to line breaks with yq?

Can't test atm but how about ("\n" + env(groups) | . style="literal") to manually prepend one, or sub("\\n"; "\n") to replace the two characters \n with a newline?

Hi, that works with "\n"+, pure magic, which I hope will not disapper with a new version of yq :D Thank you!
